# .htaccess regex redirect by file type

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I'm currently developing a site in Google App Engine as a website development platform but I eventually want to build in the capability to compile the site from dynamic templating to a static HTML/CSS-only version.

As far as the URL mapping is concerned, all of the site files exist in the site root but I still want to be able to map specific file types to folders.

For Example:

- /images - contain all images
- /scripts - contains all JavaScript files
- /stylesheets - contains all stylesheets

Right now, in GAE I'm routing these with the following static routes:

```
url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: /images/\1

url: /(.*\.css)
  static_files: /stylesheets/\1

url: /(.*\.js)
  static_files: /scripts/\1
```

How would I map these static routes using a .htaccess file containing regex rewrite rules at the site root?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GAE and don't really understand what exactly you want to achieve here. Could you provide some "real" examples of what needs to be done (from url -> to url). I think I have an idea on what you are trying to do here but I need clarification. (P.S. The actual rewrite rule should be simple)

Comment: @LazyOne The idea is, if you put site.com/image.jpg, it would map to site.com/images/image.jpg. For stylesheets, an example would be site.com/main.css -> site.com/stylesheets/main.css. The general idea is to make asset URLs as simply as physically possible without sacrificing the ability to organize files on the backend. Eventually, I'll have a folder site.com/html that will contain the static HTML/CSS pages of the whole site but I'm still working on that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this .htaccess configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$ /images/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*\.css)$ /stylesheets/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*\.js)$ /scripts/$1
```

Line 2 - 5 is only if you want apache not to rewrite if the file/link/directory actually exists.

Comment: Awesome. I especially like the addition of lines 2-5, even though I won't need it. I haven't tested to make sure this works but I'll give you the credit now anyway. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to answer this but, can this configuration also be used in httpd.conf? I have only ever played with redirect/rewrite rules in .htaccess files and if the Apache configuration file is available to edit I would like to eliminate .htaccess files (ie for speed/efficiency).

Comment: I also only played with .htaccess files. But it should be no difficulties to move it to httpd.conf. Just wrap it in a `<Directory "/var/www/html">`-tag to specify which directory it applies to.